# Dynamically adding picture using php

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I am having trouble getting a picture stored on a server and its path in my database, then i want to retrieve and showe it on the same page. So far I have the `add photo` button which `onchange` triggers the photo to a series of checks then stores it. However, because of this set up the page changes, but there's other info on the page that needs to be inputted. I am assuming I have to create some ajax function, which I have below, but it doesn't work.  Here's what I have so far.

```
<div class="step1-container">
      <h3 class="steps-detail">Step 1:</h3>
      <p>Upload a picture for you new friends</p>
      <form action="../Controllers/fileupload_controller.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        Select image to upload:
        <label class="upload-cov">
          <input type="file" name="fileToUpload" id="fileToUpload">
          <span>Add Photo</span>
        </label>
        <input type="submit" id="photoSubmit" style="display:none">
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="profile-pix">
    </div>
```

php:

```
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
    $_POST['UserId'] = $_SESSION['logname'];
    $_POST['ProfilePix'] = $target_file;
    if (storeData($_POST, $table, $cxn)) {
      $result = $target_file;
      //echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]). " has been uploaded.";
    }
```

js:

```
  $("#fileToUpload").change(function() {
      $('#photoSubmit').click();
    });
```

ajax:

```
    $('#fileToUpload').on('change', 'input', function(e) {
      e.preventDefault();
      var str = $('#fileToUpload').serialize();

      $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url:  '../Controllers/fileupload_controller.php',
        async:  true,
        traditional: true,
        data: str,
        success:  function (msg) {
          console.log(msg);

        }

    });
```

Comment: Why do you have `file` in `on('change', 'file'...` ?

Comment: it was a typo when i was retyping it thanks for pointing out but that doesnt solve the issue @JosanIracheta

Comment: Why did you change it to `input`?

Comment: @JosanIracheta wouldn't that be the selector I am operating on?

Comment: The selector is `#fileToUpload`. There's no need for `input` in the `on()`

Comment: Is the image being saved to your server?

Comment: @JosanIracheta You are absolutely right redundancy definitely exists, and not when i perform the ajax

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158276/discussion-between-josan-iracheta-and-kevlwig).

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to send a file as multi-part/form-data to the server using ajax, the easiest way will be to send the form data of the form.

Example code:

```
//from within the on change event listener
$.ajax({
  //pass the form element to the form data object 
  data: new FormData($(this).parents('form'))
})
```